# App Doesn't Crash While Debugging, but Does When Running Normally

Tags: c#, geolocation, async-await, win-universal-app, argumentexception

> System Information
>
> - Windows 10 Technical Preview (build 9926)
> - Visual Studio Community 2013
>   Attempting to debug on:
> - *[AT&T]* Lumia 635 (Windows 10 Technical Preview for phones build 9941 w/ Lumia Cyan)
> - *[AT&T]* Lumia 1520 (Windows Phone 8.1 with Lumia Denim and PfD)
> - *[Unlocked]* BLU Win Jr (Windows Phone 8.1 with PfD)
> - *[Verizon]* Lumia Icon (Windows Phone 8.1 with Lumia Denim and PfD)

---

I trying to get location services working in my app.  Previously, I had Visual Studio throw the error.  It was an `ArgumentException` with the message "`Use of undefined keyword value 1 for event TaskScheduled in async`".  Googling didn't turn up any solutions.

Here is the code:

```
Geolocator Locator = new Geolocator();
Geoposition Position = await Locator.GetGeopositionAsync();
Geocoordinate Coordinate = Position.Coordinate;
```

When I could get the error to be thrown, the exception was thrown on the 2nd or 3rd line in the sample above.
I simplified the original code to try and fix it, but this is the original:

```
Geolocator Locator = new Geolocator();
Geocoordinate Coordinate = (await Locator.GetGeopositionAsync()).Position.Coordinate;
```

The entire app works when debugging, but crashes almost instantaneously otherwise.

This is a Windows 8.1 Universal project, focusing on the phone project.

Thanks in advance

---

**EDIT:  As requested, here is the full method:**

```
private static bool CheckConnection()
{
    ConnectionProfile connections = NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile();
    bool internet = connections != null && connections.GetNetworkConnectivityLevel() == NetworkConnectivityLevel.InternetAccess;
    return internet;
}
public static async Task<double> GetTemperature(bool Force)
{
    if (CheckConnection() || Force)
    {
        Geolocator Locator = new Geolocator();
        await Task.Yield(); //Error occurs here
        Geoposition Position = await Locator.GetGeopositionAsync();
        Geocoordinate Coordinate = Position.Coordinate;
        HttpClient Client = new HttpClient();
        double Temperature;
        Uri u = new Uri(string.Format("http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v1/weather.ashx?q={0},{1}&format=xml&num_of_days=1&date=today&cc=yes&key={2}",
                                      Coordinate.Point.Position.Latitude,
                                      Coordinate.Point.Position.Longitude,
                                      "API KEY"),
                                      UriKind.Absolute);
        string Raw = await Client.GetStringAsync(u);
        XElement main = XElement.Parse(Raw), current_condition, temp_c;
        current_condition = main.Element("current_condition");
        temp_c = current_condition.Element("temp_C");
        Temperature = Convert.ToDouble(temp_c.Value);
        switch (Memory.TempUnit)
        {
            case 0:
                Temperature = Convertions.Temperature.CelsiusToFahrenheit(Temperature);
                break;
            case 2:
                Temperature = Convertions.Temperature.CelsiusToKelvin(Temperature);
                break;
        }
        return Temperature;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot connect to the weather server.");
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT 2:** I've [asked for help on Twitter](https://twitter.com/devgregw/status/564804691695919104), and [received a reply](https://twitter.com/WinDevMatt/status/564872023139024897) asking for a repro project.  I recreated the major portion of the original app, but I could not get the error.  However, errors may occur for you [so here's the project](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=CCFD696DFF6040C6!161538&authkey=!AEwWmbv4EquRqTQ&ithint=folder%2Czip).

---

**EDIT 3:  If it helps at all, here are the exception details:**

```
System.ArgumentException occurred
  _HResult=-2147024809
  _message=Use of undefined keyword value 1 for event TaskScheduled.
  HResult=-2147024809
  IsTransient=false
  Message=Use of undefined keyword value 1 for event TaskScheduled.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.Diagnostics.Tracing.ManifestBuilder.GetKeywords(UInt64 keywords, String eventName)
  InnerException:
```

Comment: You're not alone, check [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/3e505e04-7f30-4313-aa47-275eaef333dd/systemargumentexception-use-of-undefined-keyword-value-1-for-event-taskscheduled-in-async?forum=wpdevelop) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24747885/argumentexception-use-of-undefined-keyword-value-1-for-event-taskscheduled-in). As a workaround, see if this helps: `Geoposition Position = await Task.Run(() => Locator.GetGeopositionAsync());`

Comment: @Noseratio I've tried everything I could in the two threads you linked.  Also, I tried the workaround you gave.  It still works flawlessly while debugging, but it still crashes while not debugging.  Thanks for your reply

Comment: Apparently, it's a WP/WRT bug, I'd report it at http://connect.microsoft.com. BTW, try also this: `await Task.Yeild(); Geocoordinate Coordinate = (await Locator.GetGeopositionAsync()).Position.Coordinate;` Does it crash after `Task.Yeild()` or after `await Locator.GetGeopositionAsync()`?

Comment: BTW, I appreciate your're dealing with this complex stuff at your age, well done :)

Comment: @Noseratio I set it up with MessageDialogs that popup after `Task.Yield()` and `await Locator.GetGeopositionAsync()`.  My guess is that it crashes at `Task.Yield()` because none of the dialogs popup.  Again, it only does this while not debugging.  Thanks btw, haha :P

Comment: What is the home method for this code, is it an event handler? Could you edit your q. and show it?

Comment: Greg, your code is missing `await` before `Task.Yield()`, see if it makes any difference. Also what I meant is, what's the root method of the call chain leading to `GetTemperature`. Is it an `async void` UI event handler, or something like `OnLaunched`? Also, what do you see if you add `Debug.WriteLine(new { SynchronizationContext.Current })` to the beginning of `GetTemperature`?

Comment: @Noseratio Oops, I had `await` in my code, but forgot to add it in the snippet.  The stack starts from `protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)`, to a method that eventually calls `GetTemperature(false)` (awaited).  As for `Debug.WriteLine(new { SynchronizationContext.Current })`, it prints `{ Current = System.Threading.WinRTSynchronizationContext }`.

Answer (score 1):

Having checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24747885/argumentexception-use-of-undefined-keyword-value-1-for-event-taskscheduled-in) and [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/3e505e04-7f30-4313-aa47-275eaef333dd/systemargumentexception-use-of-undefined-keyword-value-1-for-event-taskscheduled-in-async?forum=wpdevelop), I believe this is a bug in [.NET `async/await` infrastructure for WinRT](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsappdev/archive/2012/04/24/diving-deep-with-winrt-and-await.aspx). I couldn't repro it, but I encourage you to try the following workaround, see if it works for you.

- Factor out all asynchronous awaitable calls from `OnNavigatedTo` into a separate `async Task` method, e.g. `ContinueAsync`:

  ```
  async Task ContinueAsync()
  {
      Geolocator Locator = new Geolocator();
      Geoposition Position = await Locator.GetGeopositionAsync();
      Geocoordinate Coordinate = Position.Coordinate; 

      // ...

      var messageDialog = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("Hello");
      await messageDialog.ShowAsync();

      // ...
  }
  ```
- Remove `async` modifier from `OnNavigatedTo` and call `ContinueAsync` from `OnNavigatedTo` like this:

  ```
  var scheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
  Task.Factory.StartNew(
      () => ContinueAsync(), 
      CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, scheduler).
      Unwrap().
      ContinueWith(t => 
      {
          try
          {
              t.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
              Debug.WriteLine(ex);
              throw; // re-throw or handle somehow
          }
      }, 
      CancellationToken.None,            
      TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnRanToCompletion, 
      scheduler);
  ```

Let us know if it helps :)

---

**Updated**, apparently, the bug is somewhere in the TPL logging provider, [`TplEtwProvider`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/TPLETWProvider.cs,e38cada0f78eafb7). You can see it's getting created if you add the below code. So far, I couldn't find a way to disable this event source (either directly or via Reflection):

```
internal class MyEventListener : EventListener
{
    protected override void OnEventSourceCreated(EventSource eventSource)
    {
        base.OnEventSourceCreated(eventSource);
        if (eventSource.Name == "System.Threading.Tasks.TplEventSource")
        {
            var enabled = eventSource.IsEnabled();

            // trying to disable - unsupported command :(
            System.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource.SendCommand(
                eventSource, EventCommand.Disable, new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>());
        }
    }
}

// ...
public sealed partial class App : Application
{
    static MyEventListener listener = new MyEventListener();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I still can't get this to work.  I have no idea why this is happening and I see that many other people are getting this too.

Comment: Hi Greg - I think this is a bug.  I'll file it and update you when I know more.  I can't promise how fast a fix will come.  Please post a link to a reproduction project on OneDrive and I'll have something to forward to the PG.

Comment: @MattSmall, pls see my update about `TplEtwProvider` event source. Is it possible to disable it altogether for a Windows Phone/Windows Store app?

Comment: @Noseratio I've added the code you've given and added a few `Debug.WriteLine`s to see output: http://pastebin.com/7JxbvyeC

Comment: @GregWhatley, this pastbin seems to be private, I can't see it.

Comment: @GregWhatley, you may want to keep an eye on this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28472872

Comment: @Noseratio Sorry, try it now

Comment: @GregWhatley, yeah, that's the expected output (for "Invalid command value", at least). So far, we haven't figured it out how to disable that `EventSource`.

Comment: I'll check this out but won't update until week after next as I am going to be out of the office.